# Ядро jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет. В принципе разобраться в работе jQuery можно ( и нужно). Вот даже пишу (в целях самообучения) свою библиотеку. Вопрос интересует по поводу таких конструкций, как

```
$('<div id="someID" class="someClass">this is a new div</div>');
```

Не могу сообразить реализацию. Неужели jQuery регуляркой парсит такие выражения, вытаскивая из него название элемента, атрибуты, innerHTML и т.д., а потом создает элемент? Можно ли сразу каким-то образом превратить выражение в скобках в html-код? Ведь, если использовать метод innerHTML необходимо создавать дополнительный элемент и в него загружать html-фрагмент.

Что бы разобраться в самой библиотеке jquery наверное мне не хватит мозгового вещества. Если кто-нибудь знает, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: ну в данном конкретном случае он скорее всего делает что-то типа

    var a=document.createElement('div');
    a.innerHTML='<div id="someID" class="someClass">this is a new div</div>';
    var out=a.childNodes

Comment: @eicto,о_О, я иду правильным путем!Просто подзабыл про childNodes!

Comment: [где-то здесь](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L192)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beH6N/)

```
var createDocumentFragment = (function ()
{
    var frag  = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        elem  = document.createElement('div'),
        range = document.createRange && document.createRange();
    frag.appendChild(elem);
    range && range.selectNodeContents(elem);
    return range && range.createContextualFragment ?
        function (html) 
        {
            if (!html) return document.createDocumentFragment();
            return range.createContextualFragment(html);
        } :
        function (html) 
        {
            if (!html) return document.createDocumentFragment();
            elem.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            while (elem.firstChild)
                frag.appendChild(elem.firstChild);
            return frag;
       };
}());
```

Comment: @Вадим Шушляков, я не проверял код, он рабочий? Надеюсь, рабочий. Спасибо, я сделал сам, но намного проще и с меньшей функциональностью.